# How to find the value of the integral $\int_{-N}^{-2}\frac{1}{1+x}\text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The below integral:
$$\int_{-N}^{-2}\frac{1}{1+x}\text{d}x$$

where $N \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $N>2$, represent the area surrounded by:$x=-N,x=-2,y=0,y=\frac{1}{1+x}$. how to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = 1 + x$; then $du = dx$.

Then we have $$\int_{-N}^{-2} \frac{1}{1+x}dx = \int_{-N+1}^{-1} \frac{1}{u}du = (\ln|u|)|^{-1}_{-N+1} = (\ln(1) - \ln(N-1)) = -\ln(N-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

The antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is just $\ln(|1+x|)$ and so the integral is 
$$
  \int_{-N}^{-2} \frac{1}{1+x} dx
= \left. \ln(|1+x|) \right|^{-2}_{-N}
= \ln(N-1)
$$